# Image in the HTML email message

Tags: python, html, mime-types, sendmail, mime-message

I am working with a Python function that sends mails wich include an attachment and a HTML message......I want to add an image on the HTML message using

`<img src="XXXX">`

When I try it, the message respects the tag, but does not display the image I want (it displays the not found image "X").....

does anyone know if this is a problem with the MIME thing....because i am using the MIMEMultipart('Mixed').....

or it is a problem with the path of the image (I'm using the same path for the atachment file and there is no problem with it)....

I dont know what else could it be!!

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have you considered remote images? (link the images back to your site). It will be lighter on the user in case he doesn't want to download images. In any case, you should make sure your message is clear even without images.

Comment: I'm not using a site....I'm sending an email, with the image (from a file on the server) displayed as part of the message!!

Comment: You need to use remote images (using HTTP) - ie. http://www.domain.com/RH/images/image.jpg (as I gather from a comment) - if you don't want to attach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html you need the fully qualified path to the image: `http://yourdomain.com/images/image.jpg`

You should be able to take the URL in the image tag, paste it into the browser's address bar and view it there. If you can't see it, you've got the wrong path.

Comment: The image path of the server is: /var/www/RH/images/image.jpg How do I put it with the HTTP as you mention???

Comment: That's the local file path. The image needs to be served up via HTTP. You need to host it on a public web server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `src="cid:ContentId"` to refer to an attached image, where `ContentId` is the ID of the MIME part.

Comment: The image I need to show is not the one I am attaching.....I want the image to be display without beeing attached!!!

Comment: Then you need an absolute path, including a domain name.